# C# define a global variable that can point to different 2d arrays depending on a random number

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers

I'm fairly new to C# and programming in general.
Right now to get started I'm trying to program a Tetris game on my own.

I defined several different 2d arrays (of different sizes) that represent the various Tetris bricks, then depending on a random number I spawn a random brick. While that brick is falling I have methods that need the 2d array of that particular brick as an input. What is the best/most efficient way of giving my methods the array as an input?

I want something like this for exmaple:

```
private void CollisionCheck(int[,] brickMatrix)
```

with `brickMatrix` pointing to one of my other 2d arrays depending on my random number.

The only solution I could think of which doesn't seem very nice is with a lot of if-statements when calling my methods:

```
if (randomNumber==1)
{
   CollisionCheck(array1);
}
else if (randomNumber == 2)
{
   CollisionCheck(array2);
}
*etc.*
```

But since I have quite some methods that need the array of the currently falling brick as an input this gets a bit messy.
So I would like to define once a variable/pointer that depending on my random number can give the various arrays as an input to all my methods that need them.

```
if (randomNumber == 1)
{
   currentBrick = array1[1,2]
}
else if (randomNumber == 2)
{
   currentBrick = array2[2,2]
}

CollisionCheck(currentBrick);

AnotherMethod(currentBrick);
```

I know this sounds a bit messy but I hope I could describe my problem more or less.

Comment: Use arrays :D - you could put the arrays in an indexed array and index them `CollisionCheck(arrays[randomNumber])`. `List<T>` is useful for this as it supports indexing and dynamic resizing etc

Comment: But my 2d arrays are of different sizes and I can't find how to combine arrays of different sizes in a List or 3d array

Answer (score 2):

You should focus better on the design of the application, even if it's not simple at all if you are a beginner.

You won't go far if you define your bricks as array of int: create a class that contain the definition of your particular brick, the position, the rotation and that provides general functionalities valid for each bricks.

```
public class TetrisBlock
{
  public Point Location{get; set}
  public double Angle{get; set}
  public int[,] DefinitionPoints{get; set}
  ...
}
```

By the way since you are trying to achieve collision detection you should check every tetris brick with every other (this is not entirely true). Collision detection is always the same for every kind of brick, even if their shape vary.

Define a List in which you keep trace of any spawned TetrisBlock at application level.

Define a static method in TetrisBlock class that checks for collision and that takes as input all the spawned blocks

```
public class TetrisBlock
{
  public Point Location{get; set}
  public double Angle{get; set}
  public int[,] DefinitionPoints{get; set}

  public static CheckCollision( IList<TetrisBlock> source )
  {
    ..calculation here..
  }
}
```